# How do I alter Windows 7 Media Sharing video resolution settings?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player, ps3

Is there a way of customising the quality of video output from the Windows 7 media sharing feature?

When I view videos shared from my Windows 7 Ultimate PC that have been recorded at high quality (either DivX videos or Media Center dvr-ms files) the resolution I see when viewing them on a PlayStation 3 is low and appears very pixelated.

Or is it the PS3?

Thanks for any help,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

I assume your PS3 does not support either DivX nor DVR-MS. The reason for which you see the poor quality is that Win7 transcodes the Divx/DVR-MS format to something that your PS3 can understand. (most likely MPEG2). This is a trade-off that MS did in Win7. We preffered that any format will be playable on the user device rather than having "format not supported" kind of errors. (as you will get if you share the same files from most of the media servers on the market today)

Unfortunately there is not so much you can do, since the Win7 can transcode high quality formats to a lower quality format only (lower resolution, bitrate, etc).